# C# Combobox to show different lists

Tags: c#, combobox, radio-button

I'm a bit stuck on the approach for this task.  I want to be able to provide 2 separate lists for one combobox based on a radio button selection.

I'm not looking for the exact code, but rather the approach.

1. Do I create two lists and make them visible/invisilble based on radio button selection
2. Do I create 2 arrays and based on radio button selection populate combobox items
3. Another implementation?

Without showing me the code, what approach would be seen as standard?

Thanks!

Comment: Number two makes sense to me.

Comment: Agreed, the second approach is quite typical.  Setup your arrays and hook into the radio button changed event; clear the combobox and then populate with the appropriate data.

Comment: thanks @eddie_cat - this is working just fine.  I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't going down an ancient way of doing things

Comment: Have faith in your ideas! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The recommended solution is to create 2 arrays and based on the user selection (radio button) populate the list with the appropriate data/items.